# Implementar fila (FIFO) usando um array

Tags: java, array, lista

Tenho uma lista de tamanho fixo 20, preciso que o usuário adicione matrículas, no entanto, quando clico na opção "mostrar", ele me apresenta somente o primeiro elemento que adicionei em todas as posições. Exemplo, se digito opção 1 para inserir e digito 12, todo o array é ocupado com o número 12. Como resolver?

```
public class Fifo {

    private int lista[];
    private int iniciolista;
    private int fimlista;
    private int matricula;
    private int i;





    //tem que criar as caracteristicas da classe fifo tipo oque ela é 
    Fifo(){
        lista = new int[20];
        iniciolista = -1;
        fimlista = -1;
    }

    public void adicionar (int matricula) {
            for (int i =0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            if (lista[i] == 0) {
            lista[i] = matricula;   
            }
        }
    }




    //mostrar o array
    public void mostrar () {
    for(int x = 0; x < lista.length; x++){
        System.out.println("posicao " + (x+1) + " = " +lista[x] );
    }
}

}
```

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MenuFifo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opcao, aux;
        String entra;
        int matricula;
        aux = 0;



        Fifo lista;
        lista = new Fifo();



        //A baixo a variavel "entra" ira receber o valor opcao para o usuario escolher que operação deseja fazer.
        do {
            entra = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\n\n\nMENU DE OPCOES"
                    +"\n\n\t1. INSERIR\n\t2. RETIRAR\n\t3. MOSTRAR"
                    +"\n\t4. DETONAR\n\t5. CABECA\n\t6. POPULACAO"
                    +"\n\t7. VAGAS\n\t8. PROCURAR\n\t9. VAZAR");

            opcao = Integer.parseInt(entra);


        switch(opcao){


        //inserir a matricula na lista
        case 1:

        if (aux < 20) { 
            entra = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("INSIRA O NÚMERO DA MATRÍCULA\n");
            matricula = Integer.parseInt(entra);
            lista.adicionar(matricula);
            System.out.println("/nA matricula de numero "+matricula+" foi adicionada com sucesson/n");
            aux ++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Você ultrapassou o limite da lista");
        }
        break;
        case 2:


            break;

        case 3:
            //mostrar o array 
            lista.mostrar();
            break;
        case 4:


            break;

        case 5:


            break;


        case 6:


            break;


        case 7: 

            break;


        case 8:


            break;
                }
            } while (opcao != 9);
        }
    }
```

Comment: se você olhar bem o seu método adicionar vai ver que ele está percorrendo os indexes da sua lista, mas o if só permite adicionar se ele estiver na posição 0, então qualquer coisa que você adiciona está ficando sempre no index 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se olharmos na [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), veremos que um array de `int` é inicializado com todos os seus valores iguais a zero. Então se eu tiver isso:

```
public class Fifo {

    private int lista[];

    public Fifo() {
        this.lista = new int[20];
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(lista[i]);
        }
    }
}

...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Fifo().mostrar();
}
```

O programa irá imprimir vinte vezes o número `0`. Agora voltando ao seu código (e arrumei a identação para deixá-lo mais legível):

```
public void adicionar(int matricula) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        if (lista[i] == 0) {
            lista[i] = matricula;
        }
    }
}
```

O que ele faz é percorrer toda a lista, e se o elemento for zero, ele atualiza o valor para `matricula`. Mas como todos os elementos são zero, então todos os elementos serão atualizados para `matricula`.

---

Se você quer implementar uma fila (FIFO - First In, First Out), não faz sentido percorrer a lista toda procurando elementos que possuem determinado valor. Repare que você tem variáveis para guardar o início e fim da fila, então **use-as**. Claro que usar um array não é lá a melhor maneira de fazer isso, mas enfim, ficaria algo assim:

```
public class Fifo {
    private int lista[];
    private int inicio;
    private int fim;
    private boolean vazia;

    public Fifo() {
        this.lista = new int[20];
        this.inicio = 0;
        this.fim = 0;
        this.vazia = true;
    }

    public boolean isCheia() {
        return this.inicio == this.fim && !this.vazia;
    }

    public void adicionar(int valor) {
        if (isCheia()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fila cheia");
        }
        this.lista[this.fim] = valor;
        this.fim = (this.fim + 1) % this.lista.length;
        this.vazia = false;
    }

    public int remover() {
        if (this.vazia) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fila vazia");
        }
        int valor = this.lista[inicio];
        this.inicio = (this.inicio + 1) % this.lista.length;
        this.vazia = this.inicio == this.fim;
        return valor;
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        int inicio = this.inicio;
        if (this.isCheia()) {
            System.out.println(this.lista[this.inicio]);
            inicio++;
        }
        for (int i = inicio; i != this.fim; i = (i + 1) % this.lista.length) {
            System.out.println(this.lista[i]);
        }
    }

    public int getTamanho() {
        System.out.println(this.inicio + ", " + this.fim);
        if (this.vazia)
            return 0;
        if (this.isCheia())
            return this.lista.length;
        if (this.fim > this.inicio)
            return this.fim - this.inicio;

        return this.fim + this.lista.length - this.inicio;
    }
}
```

Mudei os nomes `inicioLista` e `fimLista` porque me parece redundante indicar que são o início e fim da lista. Se esses campos pertencem à classe `Fifo`, então obviamente eles representam o início e fim da mesma, então deixei os nomes simplesmente como `inicio` e `fim`.

Removi a variável `i` porque não faz sentido ela fazer parte da fila (ela nem está sendo usada, aliás, o `i` que tem no `for` é outra variável, que só existe naquele escopo), e `matricula` também foi removido porque uma fila vai ter várias matrículas, não entendi porque cada fila deveria ter uma matrícula associada.

No método que adiciona eu atualizo somente o índice final, pois em uma fila (FiFo), os elementos são adicionados no fim. Para incrementar o índice, eu uso `%` que é o resto da divisão, assim eu garanto que o índice não ultrapassa o tamanho do array (se eu estiver no último índice, ele volta para o início do array).

O mesmo vale para o método que remove, só que neste eu atualizo o índice inicial. Para imprimir, eu mostro somente os elementos que foram adicionados. Não tem porque percorrer o array inteiro se nem todos os elementos fazem parte da fila.

Repare que há alguns ajustes para quando a lista está cheia. Isso porque estou usando o array de forma "circular", ou seja, os índices vão sendo incrementados, mas se chegarem ao final do array, eles voltam para o início. Então se eu ficar adicionando e removendo várias vezes, posso acabar em uma situação em que o início é 10 e o fim é 2, por exemplo (então para percorrer a fila devo começar no índice 10, ir até o fim do array e em seguida voltar no início e ir até o índice 2).

Por causa disso, tanto a fila vazia quanto cheia terão os índices inicial e final iguais, por isso tem um campo a mais para indicar se a fila está vazia.

Um exemplo de uso:

```
Fifo f = new Fifo();
f.mostrar();
f.adicionar(1);
f.adicionar(5);
f.adicionar(10);
f.mostrar();

System.out.println("Remover: " + f.remover());
f.mostrar();
```

Saída:

```
1
5
10
Remover: 1
5
10
```

---

Se não for um exercício e precisar de uma fila, use [as implementações já existentes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;


Queue<Integer> fila = new LinkedList<Integer>();
fila.add(1);
fila.add(5);
fila.add(10);
for (int i : fila) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
System.out.println("Remover: " + fila.poll());
for (int i : fila) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

A saída é a mesma do código anterior.

Se quiser controlar o tamanho máximo da fila, use `fila.size()` para verificar (algo como `if (fila.size() == 20) { não pode mais adicionar }`, etc).